# python pandas dataframe values to 0 1

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, transpose, one-hot-encoding

| Name | yr |
| --- | --- |
| Dave | 2019 |
| Dave | 2020 |
| stu | 2019 |
| stu | 2021 |

and I want to result like

| Name | 2019_yr | 2020_yr | 2021_yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dave. | 1. | 1. | 0 |
| stu. | 1. | 0. | 1 |

I tried to do use get_dummies but the result is like

| Name | yr_2018 | yr_2019 | yr_2021 | yr_2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dave | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Dave | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| stu | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| stu | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need `0, 1` ouput is necessary aggregate `max`:

```
#Name is column
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Name')).groupby('Name').max()
```

---

```
#Name is index
df = pd.get_dummies(df).groupby('Name').max()
```

Or:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['yr']).add_suffix('_yr').clip(upper=1)
```